# Liferay Portal: Avoid scrolling after navigation

Tags: scroll, liferay, liferay-6

I have this page in a Liferay 6.0.5 portal which contains of a looong Document Library list, and at the bottom of the page (several screen-heights down, normally) there's a custom portlet with some editing tools. When a user navigates with the tool links, he or she always has to do a lot of annoying scrolling down to the lower portlet to continue his/her work, and I'm looking to fix this.

Looking through the source, I came across the following in `/html/common/themes/bottom_js.jspf`:

```jsp
<%
    String scroll = ParamUtil.getString(request, "scroll");
%>
<c:if test="<%= Validator.isNotNull(scroll) %>">
    Liferay.on(
        'allPortletsReady',
        function(event) {
            document.getElementById('<%= HtmlUtil.escape(scroll) %>').scrollIntoView();
        }
    );
</c:if>
```

However, the parameter `scroll` is a non-namespaced ("global") request parameter. Is it possible to generate such URL parameters through the portlet API? (I.e., using `<portlet:renderURL>` or possibly `<liferay-portlet:renderURL>`?

Of course, I'll happily take suggestions to other solutions as well!

Regards

Gustav

Comment: I believe this is linked to https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/8118232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, Liferay's implementation of `PortletURL` handles the URL parameter `scroll` (and a handful of others) in a special way - it is *not* namespaced.